# PANDAS from loop print one excel fille with many sheets

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have this problem

```
for  excel in excel_folder:
    …………
    .....
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(n, engine='xlsxwriter')  
    pe_df_1.to_excel(writer,index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')    
    writer.save()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(c, engine='xlsxwriter')  
    pe_df_2.to_excel(writer,index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')    
    writer.save()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(g, engine='xlsxwriter')  
    pe_df_3.to_excel(writer,index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')    
    writer.save()
```

with this way I make many new excel filles with one sheet

the problem is:

how can make one new excel file with many sheets ?
The name from each sheet must be the same from each excel name

Comment: You need to call `save()` only once and, depending on the rest of your code, you may need to move the creation of the writer object and the save outside the loop.

Comment: @jmcnamara   :  I try it but the excel file has only 3 sheets from last loop....all the others before dont save it in my excel file...

Comment: In that case the `writer = pd.ExcelWriter()` and `writer.save()` need to be outside the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you ...!!!! you have right ...!! it works perfect...!!!